# Can I install c-ares 1.18.1 on Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: 21.10

I have a problem with a program that uses c-ares and I've been told to update my c-ares to version 1.18.1.

I ran `apt list libc-ares-dev` and the output was

```
Listing... Done
libc-ares-dev/impish,now 1.17.1-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
libc-ares-dev/impish 1.17.1-1ubuntu1 i386
```

Is there a way of installing 1.18.1 on Ubuntu 21.10? If I download the source code and do a manual install will it overwrite the package I currently have installed? Or will it install to some other location? I'm guessing there is no package available for 1.18.1?

Comment: What is "a program"? Can you lower its dependency requirements? Only 22.04 LTS will [have 1.18](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/libc-ares-dev).

Comment: @N0rbert The program is an app I'm developing. It has an error and hence I was told to update. When will 22.04 be available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install this *libc-ares-dev (1.18.1-1)* library manually on Ubuntu 21.10 using packages [from upcoming 22.04 LTS](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/libc-ares-dev), by commands shown below:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/c-ares/libc-ares2_1.18.1-1_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/c-ares/libc-ares-dev_1.18.1-1_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install ./libc-ares2_1.18.1-1_amd64.deb ./libc-ares-dev_1.18.1-1_amd64.deb
```